# Showing that $(1-u)z^2\leq P(uz\leq |X|)$ when $0<u<1, E(X^2)=1, $ and $0<z<E(|X|)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

I am trying to show that

> $$(1-u)z^2\leq P(uz\leq |X|)$$ where $0<u<1, E(X^2)=1, $
>    and $0<z<E(|X|)$.

I've been given a hint to consider Cauchy-Schwarz, however, I don't see where this could apply.  I have been thinking maybe I could combine it with Markov's or Chebyshev's inequalities, to turn the condition on $E(X^2)$ into a condition on the probability $P(uz\leq |X|)$, but I don't see how to do it.

Could I get a further hint, please?

Answer (score 5):

Dedimensionalizing all this to get rid of the constraints on $E(X^2)$ and $z$ is cumbersome but it can be done and it shows that the inequality to prove is equivalent to the following statement:

> For every nonnegative integrable random variable $X$ and every $t$ in $(0,1)$, $$P(X\geqslant tE(X))\geqslant\frac{(1-t)(E(X))^2}{E(X^2)}.\tag{$\ast$}$$

For every nonnegative integrable random variable $X$ and every $t$ in $(0,1)$, [Paley-Zygmund inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality) (based on the so-called second-moment method) yields the weaker statement:

> $$P(X\geqslant tE(X))\geqslant\frac{(1-t)^2(E(X))^2}{E(X^2)}.$$

Using the "sharp" inequality mentioned in the link, one can probably show that the inequality stated in the question and reformulated as $(\ast)$ above (that is, with the factor $1-t$ instead of $(1-t)^2$ in the RHS) does not hold in general.